# ¿Como puedo validar dos atributos en un modelo en rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Buenas tardes amigos de stackoverflow.

Tengo el siguiente modelo que es una tabla debil de muchos a muchos en la cual esta quiero validar dos atributos que no se repitan esos mismos dentro de la tabla permisiones un ejemplo:

tengo grupos y actividades lo que deseo es que el grupo y la actividad esas dos no se repitan internamente en cuya tabla base de datos.

Ayudenme estoy que me reviento la cabeza.

Aqui el modelo:

Permission.rb

```
class Permission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :activity
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Group.rb

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :users, through: :memberships 
    has_many :permissions
    has_many :activities, through: :permissions
    has_many :users, through: :memberships
    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

Activity.rb

```
class Activity < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :permissions
    has_many :groups, through: :permissions
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pon la siguiente validacion en Permission.rb

```
validates :activity_id, uniqueness: { scope: : group_id }
```

o de la siguiente manera también debe funcionar

```
validates :activity, uniqueness: { scope: : group }
```

Con esto no tendras repetidos en la tabla permissions.

Comment: Gracias vale me ayudo a resolver mi problema.